# Which one should be chosen for making a transposition of matrices: `fourIdx`, `leftidx`, `tensor`, `subsupscripts`, `mathtools`?

Tags: math-mode, subscripts, superscripts

I want to get a transposition symbol of matrices like `^t(1 2 3)`, as title. I used the macro `\prescript` (in mathtools) at present.

There is no any problem occured, these packages' macros work well. I just want to know whether there is some rules to help distinguishing them.

Comment: And what is wrong with that? You should add the actual problem description.

Comment: Oh, I just want to konw if there is some kind of rules or specifications to help choosing the packages in this situation.

Comment: Why should there be rules? But possibly there are several (identical) solutions.

Comment: If all the packages provide a solution, and they are equally easy to use, there's not really any way to choose. But if you are using, say, mathtools anyway (it provides many nifty extensions of amsmath), I would probably use its solution, in order to minimize the number of `\usepackage`s, and thus reducing the risk of conflicts. Also, you could look at the documentations for the various packages and see if they are actively maintained.

Comment: @Villemoes: Maybe you could add that as an answer (so that this question goes of the unanswered list).

Comment: @Caramdir: OK. I guess there's no really good answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

If all the packages provide a solution, and they are equally easy to use, there's not really any way to choose. But if you are using, say, mathtools anyway (it provides many nifty extensions of amsmath), I would probably use its solution, in order to minimize the number of `\usepackage`s, and thus reducing the risk of conflicts. Also, you could look at the documentations for the various packages and see if they are actively maintained.